# XAML Databinding property is not calling get for the second time, for a particular variable in property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I just want to make things clear about databinding, so I try things. I want to change contents of some dependency objects dinamically using with binding methods.

Basically what I try to accomplish is writing something in datePickerApp; and show it in richTextBoxComplaint dinamically. (with Button_CLick_2)

It kinda works for the first time I call the property; but for the second time it is not get updated

When I debug the code, beside the first click, I see that it sets the corresponding value but not going inside of the object and calling get for the particular value that I want to see.

I tried to add DataContext=this; to my main function and UpdateSourceTrigger values to my binding objects but still doesn't work.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<GroupBox Header="Randevu Paneli" Height="233" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="208" DataContext="{Binding Appointment, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=ViewRoot}">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height ="210" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel Width="55" Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Branş:</Label>
                            <Label Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Doktor:</Label>
                            <Label Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Tarih:</Label>
                            <Label Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Saat:</Label>
                            <Label Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Şikayet:</Label>
                            <StackPanel Height="45"></StackPanel>
                            <Button Height="25" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Çıkış</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Height="185" Width="130" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBranch" Width="115" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="comboDr" Width="115"></ComboBox>
                            <DatePicker x:Name="datePickerApp" Width="115" Text="{Binding Date}"></DatePicker>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="timePickerApp" Width="115" SelectedItem="{Binding Hour}"></ComboBox>
                            <RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBoxComplaint" Width="115" Height="44">
                                <FlowDocument>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Date}"></Run>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </FlowDocument>
                            </RichTextBox>
                            <Button Width="115" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_2">Randevu Talep Et</Button>
                            <Button Width="115" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_1">Bilgilerini Düzenle</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
```

And my .cs with corresponding areas:

```
Appointments _appointment;

        public Appointments Appointment
        {

            get
            {
                return _appointment;
                
            }

            set
            {
                _appointment = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Appointment");
            }
        }
```

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
```

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            app.Date = datePickerApp.Text;
            Appointment = app;
        }
```

As I said it works for the first click but that's it. It shows the old value for other tries. Somehow get doesnt work properly; it works for the object itself but not for the 'Date' variable in particular.

When I debug the code in first click, I see that it goes to 'Appointments' class and call get 'Date' in particular. But it doesnt work the same way for other clicks.

What could I missing?

Comment: `Appointment = app;` will not trigger any Binding if `app` is identical to the value that the Appointment property already holds. You have to assign a new Appointments instance.

Comment: Why aren't you just setting date on appointment? And raising propertychanged in the date setter. And why isn't date a datetime? It's a bad idea to use the text from a datepicker rather than datetime selecteddate.

Comment: @Clemens It works in that way thanks. But what I don't understand is I change the value Date, which is inside of the app object. and after that I assign it to Appointment property again. Why its not get triggered in that way? I mean Appointment is not getting a new value ok but Appointment.Date does? It doesnt make any difference?

Comment: It would work if Appointments would implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and the Date property would fire the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: @Clemens`public partial class HastaDetay : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged` I used that but still wasn't work in that way; you meant something else beside this?

Comment: "*if Appointments would implement INotifyPropertyChanged*" - not sure what's unclear about that.

Comment: @Clemens I created another propertychanged event inside of the Appointments class; for the Date variable. I think thats what you meant say. And now its working the way Id like to see. Thanks for the tips.